# Angular 5 BehaviorSubject populated by Observable query

Tags: angular

I'm trying to display the number of notifications my user has in the header and poll for that every 5 seconds.

I have a notifications service:

```
export class NotificationService {
  readonly baseUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/notification`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getNotificationCountForUser(userid): Observable<number> {
    return Observable.interval(5000)
    .switchMap(() => this.http.get<number>(this.baseUrl + '/getNotificationCountForUser?UserId=' + userid));
  }
```

And I am trying to load this into a `BehaviorSubject` into my header:

```
    export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

        private notificationCountSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
        notificationCount = this.notificationCountSubject.asObservable().share();

        constructor(private, private notificationService: NotificationService,
            private router: Router) { }

        ngOnInit() {
             this.notificationCountSubject.next(this.notificationService.getNotificationsForUser(this.currentUser.id));
              // I get the user id from a separate function, have left it out in my question

                }
            })

        }
```

I have the syntax for `this.notificationCountSubject.next` incorrect, I should be passing a number, but I'm passing an `Observable` instead and I'm not sure how to approach this.

Should I be loading my `BehaviorSubject` in my service, instead of my component?  What do I then pass?

**Update**

I've tried putting this all into my Notifications Service:

```
export class NotificationService {
  readonly baseUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/notification`;

  private notificationCountSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
    public readonly notificationCount = this.notificationCountSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getNotificationCountForUser(userid): Observable<number> {

    return this.notificationCountSubject.next(
      Observable.interval(5000)
      .switchMap(() => this.http.get<number>(this.baseUrl + '/getNotificationCountForUser?UserId=' + userid))
    );     
  }
```

but getting 'Argument of type 'Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.'

Comment: Small note: [`BehaviorSubject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md) uses the American spelling (without a "u").

Comment: Why? Why not simply expose the observable returned by getNotificationCountForUser? And why do you initialize a BehaviorSubject<number> with an empty object (which is clearly not a number)?

Comment: These are good questions @JBNizet that show my limited knowledge of the subject matter, not sure how to tie all this together, first time using BehaviourSubjects

Comment: Also, don't I need to put the result of the observable into a BehaviourSubject so I can watch for changes?

Comment: I've updated the initialiser for the BehaviourSubject

Comment: Why do you think you can't observe an Observable?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how that translates into how I fix my function

Comment: As I said, I see no need for a BehaviorSubject at all. Just expose the observable returned by the service directly in the component (assuming you want to use the async pipe in the view to display its last emitted value): `notificationCount: Observable<number>;  ...  ngOnInit() { this.notificationCount = this.notificationService.getNotificationsForUser(this.currentUser.id)); }`

Comment: That did it, thank you, if you add it as an answer I can accept.  Is there an easy way to find out if my Observable<number> is 0? Ie, if the user has no notifications?

Comment: If it emits 0, it means the user has no notification, just as if it emits 5 it means the user has 5 notifications.

Comment: My question was more how to emit an observable in my html.  Currently I can display the count with {{notificationsCount | async }}

Comment: So, if you see 0, it means the user has no notification.

Comment: If you want to access the value several times in your template, the easiest way is probably to subscribe to the observable in the component, and assign the value to a field of your component. Then you can use the field value in your template, without async.